# Is it possible to move messages in gmail to another tab with only the keyboard?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

With Gmail's new [tabbed inbox](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-new-inbox-that-puts-you-back-in.html), is there a way to move a message to a different tab, using only the keyboard?

Selecting a message with `x`, then pressing `v` to open the `Move To` drop down, shows a list of labels, including labels with names matching the new tabs (e.g. Social, Promotions, Updates). However, choosing one of those labels results in a message like "The conversation has been moved to "Social".  Learn more  Undo":

[image: Gmail move message]

However, as you can see from this screenshot, the message does not actually show up in the Social tab. If you navigate to the (new, auto-created upon switching to the tabbed inbox UI) Social label in the sidebar, the message does show up, along with many others:

[image: Social label messages]

Which brings me to the question: is it possible to actually move a message to a different tab, using only the keyboard (not the drag-and-drop method), in the new tabbed inbox UI for Gmail?

Comment: great question. since you haven't got an answer in over 3 years I'm guessing the answer is no.... :(